# $state.go inside $stateChangeStart in app.run not working angualrjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I just can't have $state.go() working. The $on('$stateChangeStart'...); is working fine, and the console message get printed when trying to reach a protected state with no access. But the $state.go('toState.name,toParams'); doesnt work.Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Any help appreciated thanks

```js
app.run(function ($rootScope,$state) {

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState, toParams) {
    var requireLogin = toState.data.requireLogin;

  $rootScope.currentUser = true;

    if ($rootScope.currentUser === true && requireLogin === true) {

      console.log(requireLogin);
      console.log($rootScope.currentUser);
      event.preventDefault();
      $state.go(toState.name, toParams);

    } 
else {

      console.log(requireLogin);
      console.log($rootScope.currentUser);
      $state.go('login.signin');

    }


  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When redirecting default event handling should be prevented and keep in mind that switching to login will be another state transition. It should be filtered out other wise it would lead to endless loop

```
{
  if(!toState.name != 'login.signin'){
    console.log(requireLogin);
    console.log($rootScope.currentUser);
    event.preventDefault();
    $state.go('login.signin');
  }
}
```

`$state.go(toState.name, toParams);` makes no sense because this is what is going to happen by default